# Estoy tratando de colocas minas al azar en pseint

Tags: pseint

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo que hacer un juego de minas 6×6 como hago para que las coordenadas se calculen con la función azar

Answer (score 0):

Podría ser de 2 formas

1. Recorrer la matriz y en cada posición verificar si colocas mina o no:

---

```
Si azar(100)>50 Entonces
    matriz[fila,comlumna] <- "mina"
Sino
    matriz[fila,comlumna] <- "vacio"
FinSi
```

2. De acuerdo a cuantas minas quieras colocar, generas las posiciones con números aleatorios:

---

```
cantidadMinas <- 5
Para minasColocadas <- 0 Hasta cantidadMinas con paso 1 hacer
    matriz[aleatorio(1,6),aleatorio(1,6)] <- "mina"
FinPara
```

Comment: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk14e.png) no me sirve esa solución me sale esto

Comment: La sintaxis para referenciar la posición del arreglo debe ir sin espacio: matriz[posicion]